# Django admin site not opening while running from pydev in eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I have a django project with a few apps. I use Eclipse(3.8.1) with Pydev as my IDE. When I run the server from terminal, everything works fine. But when I run it from eclipse, the site itself works fine, but I cant access the inbuilt django admin panel.

I get the VariableDoesNotExist error saying it 'Failed to lookup for key['LANGUAGE_CODE]'.

In my settings.py file, the LANGUAGE_CODE is set as 'en-us'.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe you need to explicitly define the settings file to run with in the IDE? Is the settings file used when running server from IDE?

Comment: Yes, the settings file is used. I have verified that by adding some print statements, as well modifying some other settings